# How To Read Half width & full width characters from EBCDIC using Cobol copy book

Tags: parsing, cobol, talend, ebcdic

I am using Talend to convert EBCDIC file using Cobol copy book representation of EBCDIC file. but i am unable to find out Half width and Full width representation of EBCDIC character

please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by half width characters ???. Ebcidic is a 1 byte character set !!. Do you mean there is Packed-Decimal data. Packed decimal is more common but not unique to Mainframe data.

Comment: Are you talking about full/half-width characters such as the Japanese language has on computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using cobol copy book to read the EBCDIC, so `COM-4` is right data type for reading Half width as well as Full width data. `COM-3` is used to read packed decimal values

Comment: Comp-4 is normally a 2s compliment binary integer in cobol.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation for one of the most widely used code pages for EBCDIC at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebcidic).  I am unfamiliar with the idea of half width vs. full width EBCDIC.  Perhaps the [EBCDIC 930](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_930) encoding for halfwidth Katakana is what you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about double-byte character sets?  They use a shift-in and shift-out character x'0e' and x'0f' (if I recall correctly).  You will need to parse the fields as a stream and, literally, shift into double byte mode when you hit the x'0e' and return to single byte mode when you hit the x'0f'.

Comment: could you please explain more about this approach, i have EBCDIC file which has full width packed decimal data which COMP-3 in cobole copy book not able to parse.